# ESXi Password recovery

Tags: vmware-esxi, password-reset, password-recovery

I got an issue regarding lost ESXi lost password. I tried a method to reset it using linux by modifying a shadow file but still I cannot login (I created a test server and tried this method it was working. note I got a copy of all partitions before making any modification to the shadow file.All servers built on VMs so, there is no service currently running.

How can I pass this issue ? and if I delete the value of Vpxuser it will useful ?

**Please help me in this case**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the official documentation about this topic?

> https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/68079

hope you find this useful

Comment: I saw this article but the main problem is the vCenter is built upon the ESXi as I far as I know. The vCenter is not reachable since the server was shuted down that is way I assumed the vCenter is a VM and need to be turned on from ESXi.