# Reinstalling ESXi - How to retrieve data

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have lost my ESXi password and I want to reinstall the ESXi server. How can I get the Vms up and running after installing ESXi since I am using Physical SAN to store them (including Vcenter). Please note I have 2 Servers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESXi Password recovery](https://serverfault.com/questions/1068698/esxi-password-recovery)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall ESXi on your hosts. Connect the hosts to your storage. Add the storage as a datastore. Browse the datastore for each VM and add it to the inventory. Remove and re-add your hosts to your vCenter server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please give links for more details for the following points:Connect the hosts to your storage, Browse the datastore for each VM and add it to the inventory,Remove and re-add your hosts to your vCenter server